# Remove content from table and reformat the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do

My page is displaying data of the table in below format.

[image]

Is there any way to remove the content having blank value and reformat the table as below.

[image]

**Additional Details**

Any values could come blank in actual table( refer first image). I want to remove that particular `Test` row (having blank value) and reformat the table by evenly spreading remaining `Test` row with values.

Comment: So im guessing you want to remove any row that has missing data?If its only that, where do you get the source of the data from? Can you not remove the values from the source before you show them in the table? assuming there is a source.

Comment: @mahlatse Yes your understanding is correct. I can not handle the same in the source. I have to handle the same using script.

Comment: Can you post sample HTML which you have and update your question with it. Also, how many rows you want to display in each column and after how many rows the next column should appear?

Comment: Why is "Text8" removed?

Comment: @trincot Sorry for my mistake. It supposed to be blank. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```js
function editTable() {
    var idx = 0;
    var $td = $('#prodHold td:nth-child(2), #prodHold td:nth-child(4)');
    $td.each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() !== "") {
            $td.eq(idx++).text($(this).text()).prev().text($(this).prev().text());
        }
    });
    $('#prodHold tr').slice((idx+1)>>1).remove();
    if (idx % 2) $('#prodHold tr:last td').slice(-2).text(""); 
}

$(editTable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="prodHold" border=1>
<tr><td>Test1</td><td>1</td><td>Test2</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test3</td><td>1</td><td>Test4</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test5</td><td></td><td>Test6</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test7</td><td>1</td><td>Test8</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Test9</td><td>1</td><td>Test10</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test11</td><td></td><td>Test12</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test13</td><td>1</td><td>Test14</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test15</td><td>1</td><td>Test16</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Test17</td><td>1</td><td>Test18</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Test19</td><td>1</td><td>Test20</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not reformatting properly if I set value of the `Test14` to `blank`. https://jsfiddle.net/9engag1m/3/

Comment: What is there wrong about it? What would you have expected?

Comment: If you are referring the jsfiddle I mentioned in above comment then in the output `Test19` should be at the right hand side next to the `Test17`. Basically in my actual table any values could come blank. I want to remove that particular Test row of the blank value and reformat the table accordingly without keeping any unwanted space.

Comment: So you want to evenly spread. But would it then not make more sense if also Test6 would flow to the left *before* Test7, which would go to the right? Same with Test13, ...etc.? Would that suit you? I can make it like that.

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am closing this question by accepting you answer.

Answer (score 1):

So according to your sample image, I think you need like this?

### Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e1yfL1po/2/

### jQuery

```
// remove blank td pair
$('#tableID tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == ''){
       $(this).prev('td').remove();
       $(this).remove();
    }
});

// get array of all tds
var tds = $('#tableID tr td').length;
var td_arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<tds; i++){
    if($('#tableID tr td').eq(i).text()!== ''){
        td_arr.push($('#tableID tr td').eq(i).html());
    }
}

// prepare table, wrap tr for every 4 tds, *according to your table sample
var e = '<tr>';
for(var i=1; i<=td_arr.length; i++){
    if(i%4 == 0){
        e = e + '<td>' + td_arr[i-1] + '</td></tr><tr>';
    }
    else{
        e = e + '<td>' + td_arr[i-1] + '</td>';
    } 
}
// append
$('#tableID').html(e);
```

Comment: Output is not what i am expecting. It is removing whole row,

Comment: so, which part you wanna remove? your first column and second are a pair? and so do 3rd and 4th column?

Comment: I have posted sample images in my question. Refer first image where some values are blank. I want to remove content where value is blank and reformat the table as second image.

Comment: It is not working on local machine. Returning blank. I have checked through the debugger and found that value of the `$(this).text()` is always blank in // get array of all tds.

Comment: it is working now after replacing `$(this).text()` to `$(this).html()`

Comment: The `this` in the middle part refers to what? This seems wrong.

Comment: my bad, yes, this `this` should be $('#tableID tr td').eq(i).text().

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple :
Use each to loop on tr, and if a a td's on the tr is empty hide the tr (line)

```
$('table tr').each(function(){

    if($('td:empty',this).length)
        $(this).hide(); //or $(this).remove()

});
```

Comment: The purpose is not to hide the whole row. Only two cells should be "removed".