# Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined on Table reformatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reformat the table by doing some changes in the existing table in my application. I have searched on internet for below error but I haven't found any solution for this.

Error I am getting is as below:

> Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Here is my

```
function editTable()
{

// debugger;
// remove blank td pair
$('#prodHold tr td').each(function() {
    // debugger;
    if ($(this).text() == ''){
       $(this).prev('td').remove();
       $(this).remove();
    }
});


// get array of all tds
var tds = $('#prodHold tr td').length;
var td_arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<tds; i++){
     // if($(this).text()!== ''){
         // td_arr.push($('#prodHold tr td').eq(i).html());
     // }
     if($(this).html()!== ''){
         td_arr.push($('#prodHold tr td').eq(i).html());
     }

}

// prepare table, wrap tr for every 4 tds, *according to your table sample
var e = '<tr>';
for(var i=1; i<=td_arr.length; i++){
    if(i%4 == 0){
        e = e + '<td>' + td_arr[i-1] + '</td></tr><tr>';
    }
    else{
        e = e + '<td>' + td_arr[i-1] + '</td>';
    } 
}
// append
$('#prodHold').html(e);
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    editTable();

});
```

Getting error on below line

> ```
>  td_arr.push($('#prodHold tr td').eq(i).html());
> ```

Code I am using from the question posted on below

[Remove content from table and reformat the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233683/remove-content-from-table-and-reformat-the-table/46233946?noredirect=1#comment79433221_46233946)

Please guide me If I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be triggered on `$(this).html()`, because `this` does not refer to a DOM element. You are using `this` in a normal `for` loop, while you probably intended it to be used in a jQuery `each` loop callback.

Like this:

```
// get array of all tds
var tds = $('#prodHold tr td'); // not length
var td_arr = [];
tds.each(function() {
    if($(this).html()!== ''){
        td_arr.push($(this).html());
    }
})
```

NB: You should really reconsider if the erroneous code you received as an answer deserved to be marked accepted.